# how to avoid resource override when using maven to generate runnable jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have one maven project and depend one jar which contain one resource file(c3p0.xml), I copy the resource into my src/main/resource folder and change the content according to my requirements so that I can use it.

[image]

but after I run the *mvn assembly:assembly*  command, the generated jar contained resource's content is old in dependence jar not my content in src/main/resource How to handle it?

My pom.xml's key content is as followed:

```
<plugin>
            <!-- mvn assembly:assembly -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.fastcheck.RequestUrl</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: If you call 'mvn assembly:assembly'  you don't call the life cyclce which means nothing will be copied from 'src/main/resources' into 'target/classes' folder. The problem is that you need to run your build via 'mvn clean package'

Comment: @khmarbaise but how to generate executable jar by maven pacakge?

Answer (score 0):

The jar-with-dependencies assembly mechanism uses the maven dependencies you've declared, and not from what's in your resources directory.  If you want to use a newer version of a jar, declare a newer version as the dependency in your .pom file.

Comment: I want use new configure in my resource, not in dependence jar.

Comment: I generate jar file with your maven config, it works for me.
Can you post the whole maven pom file?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind maven-assembly-plugin to the build life cycle like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      [...]
</project>
```

which will be execute the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) within the package life cylce phase.